# What does this say?

Tags: перевод

[image]

Picture taken during a tour of the Chernobyl facility. I assume it is in Russian.

Comment: it looks like a door in a hospital. And the plate says "[п/о] ward". I cannot guess what the "п/о" stands for, it is a contraction of unknown meaning to me.

Answer (score 7):

It's an abbreviation for "послеоперационная палата" which means "postoperating room", "recovery room" in hospital.